# Wordpress ajax database calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am struggling with getting ajax to work, if someone can guide me, it'd be greatly appreciated.

I am building this as a plugin.

I have a file named courselinkscript.js and contains this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

jQuery(".courselist").change(function () {

    jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: { 'action': 'getLinkedCourses' }
            //where/what do I put here to work with the data I received. 
    })


    });
});
```

Then in my main php file named course-listing.php I have this

```
function getLinkedCourses() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT list.ID, list.course, list.cost, list.length, link.CourseID FROM `wp_course_list` AS list INNER JOIN `wp_course_link` as link ON (list.ID=link.LinkID) WHERE link.CourseID = 1', OBJECT );
    echo json_encode($results);

wp_die();

}


function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('courselinkscript', plugins_url('courselinkscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('courselinkscript');
wp_localize_script( 'courselinkscript', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_list', 'getLinkedCourses' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

My calls to ajax don't work as I don't understand what needs to be done to initalise it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please confirm your url within ajax request is correct. you can try alert() to know where is the issue

Comment: I am getting ReferenceError: my_ajax_object is not defined, I am unsure of how to do the url part.

Comment: I found how to fix that I think, I had the wrong name for the localise script

Comment: Great.....most of the time issues in ajax are due to wrong url, my_ajax_object was to be intialized earlier

Comment: What do I do now? I am confused as to where I start using the data ajax sends me

Comment: Have you corrected your url now? you need to correct that first and check in debugging tool whether ajax call is being sent or not.

Comment: try intializing object as done here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below mentioned code. It should work.

```
function getLinkedCourses() {
   global $wpdb;
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT list.ID, list.course, list.cost, list.length, link.CourseID FROM `wp_course_list` AS list INNER JOIN `wp_course_link` as link ON (list.ID=link.LinkID) WHERE link.CourseID = 1', OBJECT );
   echo json_encode($results);

  wp_die();

}


function wpb_adding_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('courselinkscript', plugins_url('courselinkscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.0', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('courselinkscript');
   wp_localize_script( 'courselinkscript', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_getLinkedCourses', 'getLinkedCourses' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getLinkedCourses', 'getLinkedCourses' );
// add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_list', 'getLinkedCourses' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Replace your javascript with the below code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   jQuery(".courselist").change(function () {

      jQuery.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
         data: { 'action': 'getLinkedCourses' },
         //where/what do I put here to work with the data I received.
         success: function(data) {
             var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
             console.log(obj);
         },
      });

   });
});
```

Comment: This does nothing. I think you just corrected the localize script? I fixed that already. I now don't know what to do with the results/how to make them appear etc

Comment: There are few things that are missing in your script:
1. Handle name is different in wp_register_script and wp_localize_script.
2. Hook used to handle ajax request in your add_action functions is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, I have put your code in. What do I do now in the javascript file to see if the data is coming through?

Comment: put alert(my_ajax_object.ajax_url) before jQuery.ajax and see if you are getting the url.

Comment: That gets me the correct address. The Ajax call is working. How do I get my data now?

Comment: Replace your script file with the code I had added above. obj variable will have your data

Comment: Thank you! That works as I need it to! I can do the rest from here. Thank you very much for your help.